# How to output to screen in hadoop map reduce program?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I know many have already asked the same question, but most redirect the users to find the hadoop log file for the output. However, currently I am writing a program to query hbase table and I really want to display the result on the master console instead of storing it to a file.

Cloud computing is necessary as the database is large, while on strict filter provided by users, the output can be a few lines and should be displayed on screen for convenience. So, is there a way to output the results to master screen?

Comment: What type of output are we talking about? Integers, Strings, custom classes?

Comment: String, but I think even if it is integer, it is easy to cast integer to string.

Comment: That's not the point, is it? If it were only integers, you could simply use `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter` and set value.

Comment: The problem is not setting value but to output on screen (not for testing purpose but for application purpose)

Comment: I'm using Counters for application purpose already. :)